# PIG output difference on grunt and through java

Tags: apache-pig

When I run my pig script on grunt, output looks good. Below is the example

```
2013-07-08 16:58:40,640 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2013-07-08 16:58:40,647 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2013-07-08 16:58:40,647 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
((email,r@gmail.com),{(rrr24,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr10,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr20,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr23,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr9,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr8,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr22,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr21,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{})})
((email,zzzz@gmail.com),{(rrr0,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr6,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr7,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr3,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr1,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr5,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr4,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{}),(rrr2,(full_name,rachana),email,(state,ca),(birth_year,2013),(gender,female),{})})
grunt>
```

I can see the full_name, email, birth_year, gender but when I run same using java

```
package com.chegg.hwh.tracking.dao;

import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;

public class HWHDataPigMapReduce {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        PigServer pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.LOCAL);

        pigServer.registerQuery("rows = LOAD 'cassandra://hwh_tracking/users' USING org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage();");
        pigServer.registerQuery("emailgroup = group rows by email;");
        pigServer.dumpSchema("emailgroup");

    }

}
```

Output :

```
emailgroup: {group: (name: chararray,value: chararray),rows: {(key: chararray,full_name: (name: chararray,value: chararray),email: (name: chararray,value: chararray),state: (name: chararray,value: chararray),birth_year: (name: chararray,value: long),gender: (name: chararray,value: chararray),columns: {(name: chararray,value: bytearray)})}}
```

I tried using as (full_name:chararray) but no difference. What am I missing here. Can annyone help?

Comment: could you attach the code you're executing in grunt?

Comment: rows = LOAD 'cassandra://hwh_tracking/users' USING org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage();emailgroup = group rows by email;dump emailgroup;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java code you're calling `dumpSchema(String alias)`, which is similar to calling `DESCRIBE` in grunt. This is why the output is different.

You could store the result of the query as follows: `pigServer.store("emailgroup", "out");`

Try also `getExamples()`, I have never used it, though.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/PigServer.html

Comment: so what should I use to display the content ?